# How do I get javascript to write messages on my HTML-page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to write messages on my HTML-page by using ajax. However, it is not working.

```
/* Ajax*/

var marvel = {
  render: function () {
    var url = "https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?apikey=9ebf9d01b5fb12c9d36fdb5926c7f9e1";
    var message = document.getElementById("message");

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type:"GET",
      beforeSend: function() {
        message.innerHTML = "Loading...."
      },
      complete: function() {
        message.innerHTML = "Successfully done!";
      }
    });

  }
};
marvel.render();
```

```
        </section>
        <!--Body Section Starts Here-->
        <section id="bodyGrid">
            <div class="inner-grid">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Marvel</h1>
                    <p class="lead text-center" id="message"></p>
                    <div id="marvel-container">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
```

I want it to present different text while loading my Marvel Api. Nothing happens though.

Fiddle with all codes: https://jsfiddle.net/w38bj2fq/3/

Comment: All else being equal, that should work. Use the developer tools in your browser. Check for errors in the console. Check to see what happened to your HTTP requests in the Network tab if the browser.

Comment: Could you turn your code into a code snippet? and maybe try implementing setInterval() into it? Also to reduce repetitiveness you can simply add the `.innerHTML = ""` into the message variable itself.

Comment: Since you seem to be using jQuery you could also just do $('#message').html('Loading...');

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w38bj2fq/3/

Here is a fiddle with all the coding.

Comment: Hello DanielleJ, in the fiddle there's a mistake in $.$.ajax, I changed it and it was displaying "Succesfully done!" 
Please, take a look again in case you have the same typo in your code

Comment: Good spotted! How could I have missed that? However, it is still not showing in my actual website - http://www.student.city.ac.uk/~aczc972/directory.html

Comment: @DanielleJ it return a 404 error, with this data {"code":"MissingParameter","message":"You must provide a hash."}, guess you are missing something

Comment: I am trying to look into it now, although it wouldn't affect the rest of the code? I feel like the first bit should be shown? It is my API key that is making a fuss.